# system can not handle events fired on nanoseconds, why?

Tags: java, timer, timertask, nanotime

I really seek a logical explanation regarding the following. I have a `timed task`

```
static TimerTask timedTask = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("timed task");
    }
};

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(timedTask, (long) logfile.getFileHash().get(1).getTimeStampInNano());
```

when i run that code, nothing shows up in the console, but wen I change it to:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(timedTask, (long) logfile.getFileHash().get(1).getTimeStampInMilli());
```

the console displays the message in the `run()` method. It seems to me that the system could not manage to handle time in nanoseconds because they are faster than the system clock. But how it is possible while there is a method called `System.nanoTime()`, which means the system should be able to recognize that a tasks starts at specific nano seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The api documentation on [System.nanoTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()%20System.nanoTime()) says:

> This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily
>   nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes) - no
>   guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as
>   that of currentTimeMillis().

As such, the JVM might not be able to see difference in time that are smaller than 1 millisecond.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about providing nanoseconds as an argument where milliseconds are expected by the function.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understand the actual question, and the information given in the accepted answer looks correct as far as it goes.  But for the method `Timer.schedule(TimerTask, long)`, the long value is a delay *measured in milliseconds*.  It does not know or care whether the long was originally a number of nanoseconds.  Since that is billionths of a second instead of thousandths, you're going to wait many orders of magnitude longer than if it were in milliseconds.

Comment: I think you nailed the problem; the OP simply hasn't waited long enough, due to the (much) larger number involved in nano-time...

Comment: The thing about it is, even a millisecond value that represented a date would create a delay longer than anyone is liable to wait.  But I don't know whether that's what the long represents, I'm deducing that from the "getTimeStamp" part of the method name.

Comment: Now that I look at the original question again (did someone edit it for content), OP is expecting the task to start at a particular time.  Someone should therefore tell him not to cast his value to `long`, it needs to be a `Date`.